# Can't get drilldown module to work in highcharts in typescript

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, highcharts

I'm using the highcharts from npm in a typescript project. Highcharts is working great. However, I can't get a pie chart to work with a drilldown. Whenever I try to import the drilldown module I get the following error for line 3:

```
1. import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
2. import * as Drilldown from 'highcharts/modules/drilldown';
3. Drilldown(Highcharts);
```

> This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof
>   import("/node_modules/highcharts/modules/drilldown")' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

I've looked over the docs on the npm page and I'm importing exactly as their example shows but clearly something has changed. Here's the environment:

> Ionic CLI: 5.2.4
>   Ionic Framework: @ionic/angular 4.6.2
>   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
>   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
>   @angular/cli: 7.3.9
>   @ionic/angular-toolkit: 1.5.1
>
> System:
>   NodeJS: v12.3.1
>   npm    : 6.9.0
>   OS     : Linux 4.4 (Ubuntu in WSL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import and initialize the `drilldown` module in this way:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HC_drilldown from 'highcharts/modules/drilldown';
HC_drilldown(Highcharts);
```

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-module